# How to create a counter that updates via a mouse drag?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a circle, and if the user drags his mouse clockwise along the path of the circle the counter increases, and if he drags the mouse counter-clockwise it decreases. What is the best way to implement this in Java? I imagine trig will be needed so the program knows when the user is dragging clockwise or counter-clockwise, right? Not looking for code examples, just help with theory so I can begin with the right approach.

Comment: You just look at how each coordinate changes: growing or declining.

Comment: This is going to be a problem (at least in Java) because the frequency of mouseMoved & mouseDragged events means you'd be missing a lot of space/motion between events

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have access to the circle, get its center point coordinates.
Then get the coordinates of the mouse. After that you compute the angle between the vector and the `x-axis`.

You do so by first setting the circle point as the center of the imaginary coordinate system and then shifting the mouse coordinates to this system. After that you apply `atan2` on the new mouse coordinates. The result is the desired angle.

```
Point center = ...;
Point mouse = ...;
Point shiftedMouse = new Point(mouse.x - center.x, mouse.y - center.y);
double angle = Math.atan2(shiftedMouse.y, shiftedMouse.x);
```

At this point you probably need to convert the result of angle to degrees or something like that, if you like. You may take a look at [Wikipedia#atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) for this.
Of course you can also leave it in the format `(-pi, pi]` and work with that, if you know what it means.

Now you track how this angle changes. If it increases, then the mouse is moving counter-clockwise; if it decreases, then clockwise and so on (or maybe the other way around, just try it). Take care of the bound where after `359°` `0°` and then `1°` comes.